# DB, user not created using postgres docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I was setting up my django project and postgres but everytime I was getting this error

> role doesn't exist

or

> Db doesn't exist

So when I only tried to setup postgres and see if postgres is creating user and db correctly, but it wasn't

Here is my docker compose file :

```
    version: "3"
        services:
          templates_db:
            image: postgres:9.6
            ports:
             - "5432:5432"
            environment:
              - POSTGRES_USER=my_user
              - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=my_pass
              - POSTGRES_DB=my_db
            volumes:
              - ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

I ran my compose file using `docker-compose up --build` and got below logs

```
    templates_db_1  | LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2017-05-16 05:48:39 UTC
    templates_db_1  | LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
    templates_db_1  | LOG:  invalid record length at 0/14F0080: wanted 24, got 0
    templates_db_1  | LOG:  redo is not required
    templates_db_1  | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
    templates_db_1  | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
    templates_db_1  | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

- When I logged into postgres shell as

  ```
  docker exec -it **container_id** sh
  su - postgres
  $ psql
  postgres=# \l
  ```

It didn't have the db I mentioned in compose file *my_db*

Comment: For me it works without the volume mount. Can you check the data inside your mount?

Comment: @lorenzvth7 no there is no data, However when I ran this command ```docker-compose run templates_db``` then new container was created and database too . So is their anything I have to write down in compose file

Comment: So you mean it works without the volume mount? (and it doesn't work with the volume mount, even if it's empty?)

Comment: @lorenzvth7 looks like it is. But what I want is Whenever I ran ```docker-compse up``` command Database must be created so that it can be links with django application.

Comment: You have to point from your python app to the ip of the server where you start your docker-postgres (if it's on the same machine use localhost) and port 5432.(you've mapped port 5432 ofyour container on 5432 of your server) For the volume I would check the permissions.

Comment: @lorenzvth7 it was permission error.  as soon as I mentioned complete path here ```- ./data/postgres:```, database was created.  And about linking db with Python app, I have idea how to do that. Anyway thanks a lot. You can post the comment as answer , So that anyone facing same problem can resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but my problem was that I had also installed POSTGRESSQL itself.

This was caching more than it needed too and also interfering with user and password validation. After de-installing POSTGRESSQL itself, docker-compose down -v && docker-compose up -d, run application and it worked swimmingly.